# bodymovin translateZ();

Tags: javascript, css, html, after-effects, bodymovin

I created the following animation using aftereffects:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3nBp.jpg

There is a button on after effects that was used to set the movement along the z-axis:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9wcJ.jpg

I believe it is this method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ

However my resulting html5 export only applies the opacity I set in after effects to the png and ignores translateZ:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVkPG.jpg

I did not see anything about 3d or translate Z in the following documentation that I found:

https://airbnb.io/lottie/supported-features.html

How do I add the translateZ() to the png inside the exported animation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'html' renderer instead of the 'svg'?

Comment: greetings, airnan, I do not understand your answer. Can you please be more descriptive, what do you mean 'using the html renderer instead of svg?' 
I am following the following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YUDOshaFUM I am exporting from 
after effects using the bodymovin plugin, I have the following files
aeffect.json, aftereffectslogo.html, bodymovin.js, index.js, and a folder titled 'images' where it exported the png thats used in the animation

The animation is working fine, except it isnt recognizing the translateZ principle as explained above.

Comment: Im still unsure what you mean, but I just tried replacing the value of the renderer key in the animation variable inside the index.js file with the string 'html' instead of the string 'svg'.. did nothing.